# status=203/EXEC with systemd and RootDirectory=/RootImage=

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, systemd

I am trying to create a simple systemd service that uses a Golang app and `RootDirectory=/` but it always fails with `status=203/EXEC /usr/bin/app: No such file or directory`. The unit file looks like this:

```
[Service]
Type=exec
RootDirectory=/srv/image
ExecStart=/usr/bin/app
```

Inside `/srv/image` I have the following directory tree:

```
/usr/bin/app
/usr/lib/systemd/system/
/usr/lib/os-release                          
/etc/resolv.conf                             
/etc/machine-id                              
/proc/                                      
/sys/                                        
/dev/                                        
/run/                           
/tmp/                  
/var/tmp/
```

The directories and files are all readable, wriable and executable by everyone and systemd is able to find the directory and even creates additional directories when I use `BindReadOnlyPaths=` to bind paths from the host but the execution still fails. And for the same reason I can't get [portable systemd services](https://systemd.io/PORTABLE_SERVICES/) to work. I compiled the [official Golang example from the GitHub repo](https://github.com/systemd/portable-walkthrough-go) but even that fails with the exact same error message. `status=203/EXEC /bin/app: No such file or directory`

i tested this on Arch Linux (Endeavour OS Apollo) with the latest systemd 250 as well as on Ubuntu Server 22.04 with systemd 249. No luck so far.

Comment: Probably missing a file! I would run `sudo strace -f -o /tmp/strace.out chroot /srv/image /usr/bin/app` and examine the /tmp/strace.out. How did you compile your go application? Go can have problems with name lookups with the default build parameters.

Comment: Thank you. That command is really helpful and it seems like you are right. I'm missing some build parameters. I think for other apps the easiest way would be to get a copy of Alpine Linux and use that as the root file system.

Comment: Even Alpine can have issues.  You should be able to make this work without too much effort, and it would be a pity to make the container bigger just to get around this. The Makefile in the example from github you give should have the correct magic. If I write this up as a fuller answer will you accept it (unless a better answer arrives of course)?